# Customize and display navigation on the top right of header

Tags: magento2, navigation, header

I'm working with Magento 2.2.5 i want to move navigation menu to the top right of header.
also i want to know which file i can edit to customize navigation menu
Thanks.
UPDATE :
I want my headr to look like that : 
[image]

Comment: Where do you want to move, on which location in header ? Could you upload some screen shot

Comment: Ok, I updated my question with screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay you can move your navigation by `app/design/frontend/theme-folder/your-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.container" />
```

destination you can change whatever you want Then you can manage buy adding some css.